# Which for loop is the best to choose and why?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I was playing around in code and i thought of switching the for loops wondering about which would be the best way to implement this loop when it comes to storing data? I'm curious if anyone has an opinion as to which would they prefer to choose and why even when they give the same result, i am assuming it has to do with performance but I am not sure how . Thank you.

```
char data[1024ull*1024][1024];

for (uint64_t i = 0, endi = 1024ull*1024; i < endi; ++i) {
    for (uint64_t j = 0, endj = 1024; j < endj; ++j) {
        work(data[i][j]);
    }
}
```

OR

```
char data[1024ull*1024][1024];

for (uint64_t j = 0, endj = 1024; j < endj; ++j) {
    for (uint64_t i = 0, endi = 1024ull*1024; i < endi; ++i) {
        work(data[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first loop will have better cache locality.

Comment: Sequential memory access is typically faster than strided one. Now think of how `data` is stored in memory.

Comment: "i am assuming it has to do with performance" why? "but I am not sure how" measure it !!

Comment: @idclev463035818  how can i measure it? are there specific functions to do so?

Comment: I am just trying to set up a benchmark at https://quick-bench.com, though I am not very familiar with it and struggle to get a time that is not 0 ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 amazing thank you!

Comment: this is what I came up with, note that I had to decrease the size quite a bit to avoid a timeout, https://quick-bench.com/q/zmoxrItASxT4Jk4TbIslmyfwssE. Was planning to write an answer, but I am not quite convinced with my results. Even with quickbench it seems to be tricky to make the compiler not optimize the "wrong" thing

Comment: @idclev463035818 they're quite close , this gave different answer than the first two answers on this post

Comment: the first comments mention good points why one can expect them to have different performance. Fwiw, I completely agree with them. However, to know which has better performance there is no other way than to measure

Comment: i like poor analogies, so how about this one: Even if you know every detail about two cars, and if we assume that their drivers handle the car perfectly, you don't know who will win a race on a certain track before you perform the race on that track. And on a different track you might get a different result.

Comment: @idclev463035818 i got it thanks for the effort you put as well that will be useful!

Answer (score 2):

The first loop should have better cache locality, and can even be written simpler with for-range:

```
char data[1024ull*1024][1024];

for (auto& arr : data) {
    for (auto& e : arr) {
        work(elem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Flatten the array instead:

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t gibibytes = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
constexpr std::size_t data_size = 1 * gibibytes;
uint8_t data[data_size];

for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < data_size; ++i) {
    work(data[i]);
}
```

If you don't plan on modifying the array size in place (I don't know what `work` does...) you can simplify the array with a `ranged-base for loop`:

```cpp
for (auto& byte : data) {
    work(byte);
}
```

Flattening the array makes it so you don't have to worry about cache misses at all.